# How to give extended permissions in FBConnect with REST API in iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have developed an iPhone application, which is communicating data with faceBook. Initially I was only able to get basic information of user from Facebook. To post to a user's wall, I learnt about giving extended permission 'publish_stream', hence I added following code snippet:

```
- (void)session:(FBSession*)session didLogin:(FBUID)uid {

   FBPermissionDialog* dialog = [[[FBPermissionDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
   dialog.delegate = self;
   dialog.permission = @"status_update";
   [dialog show]; 

   [self getFacebookName];
}
```

And made necessary changes in the FBPermissiondialog class file.

Now this is allowing me to post to my wall, but it shows two separate dialogs for permissions, first to access user's basic information, and second for publishing permission. I want to have all permissions in a single pop-up. Also, I am using FBRequest to post to Facebook, not FBStreamDialog (as I dont want the UI for posting).

Please help me with this, I badly need to resolve this issue soon.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In FBLoginDialog.m file

```
- (void)loadLoginPage {

    NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"1", @"fbconnect", @"touch", @"connect_display", _session.apiKey, @"api_key",
    @"fbconnect://success", @"next",@"user_photos,photo_upload",@"req_perms",nil];

    [self loadURL:kLoginURL method:@"GET" get:params post:nil];

}
```

add "req_perms" key to the dictionary as shown above.

Hope this will solve your problem :)